# How to write an npm package for react native that runs Objective-C in the background

Tags: objective-c, react-native, npm

I am writing an app using react native and there is nothing in the library that allows you to subscribe to a calendar. You can do this in Objective-C with basically one line of code. Is there a way to create an NPM package that runs Objective-C in the background and just plop it in my react native project? This seems like it should be pretty simple.

Here is the line of code I've found that does what I want it to do in Objective-C.

```
NSString *url = @"http://server/filename.ics";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]
```

If I can just create some kind of component and pass it a URL from my React Native project that would be incredible. Also, I think others would find this to be useful.

edit: I should also note that I am using expo and I'd prefer not to eject and edit the xcode project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a various library available for that.

1. [react-native-create-library](https://github.com/frostney/react-native-create-library/blob/master/README.md)
2. [react-native-create-bridge](https://github.com/peggyrayzis/react-native-create-bridge)

you can use any of them as per your requirement